# Universal Google Analytics Tracking Sent/Thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, events, google-analytics, tracking

First of all I'm complete new on advance Analytic apart from just adding the main tracking code.

We want to track the message sent page on our contact from our php website(not wp) on analytics.

The contact form submit to itself for validation

How do I add a code that tracks the message sent. when php load the message "sent".

Should it be just code below next to "Sent" message and it will appear on analytic already?

```
 <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('send', 'event', 'Contace Form', 'Message Sent');
</script>
```

Comment: How is the Thank You page loaded? Is it a completely separate page (ie. URL is different), or does the page content change without changing the URL? That code you have will work provided that the GA library is already called BEFORE you send the event.

Comment: The Thank You page is loaded when form contact.php submitted to itself without detecting any error on the submission so inshort the same url but the thank you only appears when form is submitted. I added the that scrip above below the "Thank you" text.

Comment: The GA Library, the main GA tracking code is loaded on the footer just before the closing body tag. So this will not work because main tracking is on the footer :(

Comment: Loading the GA library twice is a problem because you will be tracking the page twice and sharing your data. Don't include code in a comment. Just update the question with what you've tried.

Comment: Tried the code above but I cannot seem to find anything on the analytics. Could be because the js is being called again on the footer for the main tracking? I can't touch the footer code sad to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the only GA code on your page, then it's not going to track anything because you have not actually created the GA tracking object

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-f');
ga('send', 'event', 'some category', 'some action');
```

If you already have the GA tracking code on the page somewhere else, then there's no need to include it again.

Comment: The  `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-f');` part is declared on the very footer with main page tracking for the entire site along with the other scripts.

I'm assuming it does not due to the order of the scripts? Since my thank you tracking in on the body.